# How can I efficiently enter multiple instances of data?

Tags: formatting, data-acquisition

I would like to plot the normal distribution for a population of human heights.

My question is how can I input multiple frequencies for the same variable, without writing them out one by one.

e.g. I have 17 instances of 5'10", 20 of 5'11", 4 of 6'.

Comment: Have a look at `ConstantArray` and `Join`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Join[
   Table[Quantity["5 feet 11 inches"], {7}], 
   Table[Quantity["5 feet 10 inches"], {20}]
 ]
```

So there are three things going on here -- we are using Mathematica Version 9 `Quantity` for things with units, `Table` to make individual lists of a given length, and `Join` to concatenate them.

You could also use `ConstantArray` instead of `Table`, and various different input forms of "5 feet 10 inches", etc.

Comment: I found it interesting that "5 feet 11 inches" becomes $5'11"$ which is, in FullForm, `Quantity[MixedRadix[5, 11], MixedRadix["Feet", "Inches"]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[5.10, {17}]
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

1. `Table` is best used for things that change while `ConstantArray` is optimized for repetition of a single element.
2. Rather than typing either several times it will be faster to use `Apply`.
3. Entering pairs of values is done more quickly with [matrix entry tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TypingMatrices.html) than nested brackets.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(`Flatten` or `Join` can be used to merge sub-lists into one.  I am using pre-v9 units in this example.)

All this said there may be a better way to "plot the normal distribution."